# Variables, references and pointers - Write the function zero (...) so that the following code works correctly

Tags: c++, homework, reference

I have following homework exercise from lecture **"Variables, references and pointers"**:

> Write the function zero (...) so that the following code works
>   correctly:
>       int x = 3;
>       zero(x);
>       cout << x << endl;  // writes 0

This is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void zero(int &);

int main(void) {
    int x = 3;
    zero(x);
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}

void zero(int & num) {
    num = 0;
}
```

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't too complicated, so there isn't that much to say. Your code is perfectly clear, but there are a couple things that could be improved.

---

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

This is okay-ish for beginning programming classes, but `using namespace std` should usually be avoided. See [*Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1896169)

---

> ```
> void zero(int &);
> ```

You *could* just not forward declare the function, and instead just define the function here. It's a little less code to write. It comes down to preference

---

> ```
> int main(void) {
> ```

Don't use `void` to say that a function takes no arguments. It's a C-ism, and should be avoided in C++. Just write `int main() {`.

---

> ```
> int main(void) {
>     ...
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

There's no need to have a `return 0;` at the end of `main()`. For the specific case of the `main` function, `return 0;` is implied at the end of the function.